# How can I calculate this big determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck at calculating the determinant of this $n$ size square matrix.

\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & \dots & \dots &b \\ 
b &\ddots  & \ddots &&\vdots \\
 \vdots &\ddots&&\ddots&\vdots  \\
\vdots &&\ddots&\ddots&b  \\
b &\dots & \dots & b & a
\end{vmatrix}

To calculate the determinant I want the matrix to look like this:

\begin{vmatrix}
x & * & \dots & \dots &* \\ 
0 &\ddots  & \ddots &&\vdots \\
 \vdots &\ddots&&\ddots&\vdots  \\
\vdots &&\ddots&\ddots&* \\
0 &\dots & \dots & 0 & x
\end{vmatrix}

And the determinant would be $x^n$

I have tried several things and I got

\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & \dots & \dots &b \\ 
b &\dots  & \dots &b&a \\
0 &a-b&b-a&0&0  \\
\vdots &0&a-b&b-a&\vdots  \\
\vdots &&\ddots&\ddots&0  \\
0 &\dots & \dots & a-b & b-a
\end{vmatrix}

But I can't manage to get the matrix fully diagonalized.

Comment: is the matrix all $b$s except for the diagonal where it is $a$?

Comment: Have you tried some sort of combination of induction and cofactor expansion?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Determinant

Comment: @RSerrao yes it is.

Comment: We can write this matrix as $M = (a-b)I + \frac {b}{n}xx^T$, where $x$ is the vector consisting of only $1$s.  It's very easy to find the eigenvalues of $x$, and from there find the eigenvalues of $M$.  From there, the determinant is simply the product of eigenvalues.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this question has been asked and answered before, but I'm having trouble finding the relevant question.